# Sending a file via form to email with Laravel (Localhost)

Tags: php, email, file-upload, laravel, localhost

Newbie to Laravel so be kind lol

My config for mail.php is correct and emails are being received successfully for text inputs to gmail, but not sure exactly how to complete the task for files. I would appreciate some assistance or reference links.

Thanks in advance!!

Code in routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('form');
});

Route::post('/form', function()
{
        $data = ['firstname' => Input::get('firstname'), 'username' =>        Input::get('username'), 'email' => Input::get('email'), 'resume' => Input::get('resume') ];

        $rules = array(
            'username' => 'Required|Min:7',
            'email'     => 'Required|Email',
            'firstname' => 'Required',
            'resume' => 'Required'
        );


        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            // Validation has failed.
            return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
        }

        else {

            Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('mail@domain.net');
            $message->subject('Welcome to Laravel');
            $message->from('sender@domain.net');


        });

        return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->with('success', 'Thank you for your submission.');

        }
//
});
```

Code in form.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
@if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert-box success">
    <h2>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h2>
</div>
@endif

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/form')) }}
        <p>{{ Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address');}} <br>{{    Form::email('email', 'example@mail.com');}}</p>
        {{ $errors->first('email') }}

        <p>{{ Form::label('username', 'Username');}} <br> {{Form::text('username');}}</p>
        {{ $errors->first('username') }}

        <p>{{ Form::label('firstname', 'First Name');}} <br> {{Form::text('firstname');}}</p>
        {{ $errors->first('firstname') }}

        <p>{{ Form::file('resume'); }}</p>

        <p>{{Form::submit('Send Details');}}</p>

    {{ Form::close() }}



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

First off, be sure to allow your file to accept file uploads:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/form', 'files' => true)) }}
```

After that, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
$input = Input::all();
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($input)
{
    $message->to('mail@domain.net');
    $message->subject('Welcome to Laravel');
    $message->from('sender@domain.net');
    $message->attach($input['resume']->getRealPath(), array(
        'as' => 'resume.' . $input['resume']->getClientOriginalExtension(), 
        'mime' => $input['resume']->getMimeType())
    );
});
```

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files and http://laravel.com/docs/mail#basic-usage