# Send file from form

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I need send a file (pdf) from a contact form to a email.

For now I can send the email with a empty pdf file.

This is the code that I have in my controller. Thanks!

```
public function send(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
    $data      = $request->all();


    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {

        $message->from('contact@example.com', 'Contact Form');

        $message->to('me@mail.com')->subject('test');

        if($data['document'] != '')
        {
            $message->attachData($data['document'], $data['document']->getClientOriginalName());

        }


    });


    return "Your email has been sent successfully";

}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this would make a difference, but try to specify a MIME type on the attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it work properly.

I changed

```
$message->attachData($data['document'], $data['document']->getClientOriginalName());
```

by

```
$message->attach( $data['document']->getRealPath(), [
                            'as' => $data['document']->getClientOriginalName(), 
                            'mime' => $data['document']->getMimeType()
                  ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To attach a file you can use below options :

```
// Attach a file from location
$message->attach($pathToFile, array $options = []);

// Attach a file from a raw $data string...
$message->attachData($data, $name, array $options = []);
```

**Refer below link :**
[Sending a file via form to email with Laravel (Localhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798527/sending-a-file-via-form-to-email-with-laravel-localhost)

Comment: I am using it, but when I receive the email the file is empty.

Comment: @rsancle How is the file empty?

Comment: No, the pdf received file size is 1kb and i can't open it.

Comment: Is `$data['document']` content correct in database? @rsancle

Comment: I take it from a form, not from a database. Maybe should I move the file to other path before than send a mail?

Comment: Hope this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798527/sending-a-file-via-form-to-email-with-laravel-localhost @rsancle

Comment: Thanks! It helped me :D

Answer (score -1):

Are you using PHPMailer?

To use PHPMailer:

- Download the PHPMailer script from here: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient
  place in your project.
- Include the main script file --
  require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');

Set the Headers:

```
 $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
```

Also: PHPMailer, provides this itself,

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$file_to_attach = 'filepath';
$email->AddAttachment($file_to_attach , 'filename + file extension');
$email->Send();
```

Comment: I am using laravel 5.1, and it should work using the frameworks tools.

Comment: I'd advise against downloading an external library yourself and instead use composer, i.e.: `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`.