# laravel 5.4 email attach files from user input

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.3

I want to attach file on email from user input files on application form, but I dont know hot to do it properly. I tried this code but the attached files are invalid files(pictures, pdf etc..) when opening after downloading the attached files. Here is my code

```
public function __construct(Request $request, Position $position)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->position = $position;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $email = $this->from('xxxx@xxxxx.com', $this->request->first_name . ' ' . $this->request->last_name)
        ->replyTo($this->request->email, $this->request->first_name . ' ' . $this->request->last_name)
        ->subject('Application for ' . $this->position->name)
        ->view('emails.application');


        $counter = 1;
        foreach($this->request->resume as $resume) {

            if ($resume->isValid()) {
                $path = $resume->path();
                $extension = $resume->extension();

                $email->attachData($path, 'file' . $counter. '.' . $extension);
            }

            $counter++;
        }

    return $email;
}
```

Comment: tried to define the mime type, check out the docs #Raw Data attachment https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#attachments

Comment: @ranjeet id tried this
 $email->attachData($path, 'file' . $counter. '.' . $extension, [
                        'mime' => 'application/' . $extension,
                    ]);
and just insert pdf files so i know that mime type will be correct but still can't open by any pdf reader

Comment: try `$email->attach($path);`

Comment: @manix the attached file became phpXXXX.tmp

Comment: Oh right!  Let me test attachData function

Comment: @manix and ranjeet problem solve with
$email->attach($path, [
                         'as' => 'file' . $counter. '.' . $extension,
                        'mime' => 'application/' . $extension,
                    ]);
i just need to create an array of extention mime type to support all the file acceptable of my application thanks

Comment: by the way i saw this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798527/sending-a-file-via-form-to-email-with-laravel-localhost) but i think its not consider as duplicate because the sending method is different and i use laravel 5.4 as mention on the title of my question, and also why i use attachDate coz i saw the documentation which say use it when you dont want to save on disck just on memory os i used it first